# ERROR Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I wanted to use `react-native-activity-recognition` dependancy on my React native project to track user's activity. but when I start running the app, I could see this error,
I use `hermes` on this project. `React native: 0.70.1v`

github: https://github.com/Aminoid/react-native-activity-recognition#readme

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 10): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

This is how I use this library on my code as per the documentation.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ActivityRecognition.subscribe(detectedActivities => {
      const mostProbableActivity = detectedActivities.sorted[0];
      console.log(mostProbableActivity);
    });
    
    return ActivityRecognition.stop();
  });
```

I also declared a `custom.d.ts` file but same thing goes on! Help me to fix this issue!

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: @Riku No, not yet